# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Powershell Script MSDeploy Error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, msdeploy

I have a .NET web solution in Azure DevOps. I'm trying to set up CI for my dev subdomain. So far I have followed [this article](https://www.mozcode.com/blog/use-azure-devops-free-cicd-on-smarterasp-shared-hosting-no-more-excuses/) to set up my build pipeline which appears to be working.

So, I followed [part 2 of that article](https://www.mozcode.com/blog/free-azure-devops-cicd-with-smarterasp-net-hosting-part-2) to set up the release pipeline. Which has me put the following in my PowerShell Script MSDeploy task:

```
_MYSITE-ASP.NET-CI-Try2\drop\MYSITE.deploy.cmd /Y /M:hardcoded /U:MYUSERNAME-001 /P:$(smarteraspPassword) /G:False /A:Basic -allowUntrusted -enableRule:AppOffline
```

(With MYUSERNAME and MYSITE replaced appropriately)

For reference the MYSITE.deploy.cmd file is long but starts with this:

```
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Copyright 2008 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
@rem This is provided as sample to deploy the package using msdeploy.exe
@rem For information about IIS Web Deploy technology,
@rem please visit https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
@rem Note: This batch file assumes the package and setparametsrs.xml are in the same folder with this file
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@if %_echo%!==! echo off
setlocal
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Please Make sure you have Web Deploy install in your machine. 
@rem Alternatively, you can explicit set the MsDeployPath to the location it is on your machine
@rem set MSDeployPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\"
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem if user does not set MsDeployPath environment variable, we will try to retrieve it from registry.
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if "%MSDeployPath%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy" /s  ^| findstr -i "InstallPath"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "InstallPath" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
if "%%~dpj" == "%%j" ( 
set MSDeployPath=%%j
))))))

@rem ------------------------------------------

@rem ------------------------------------------

                      
if not exist "%MSDeployPath%msdeploy.exe" (
echo. msdeploy.exe is not found on this machine. Please install Web Deploy before execute the script. 
echo. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
goto :usage
)

set RootPath=%~dp0
if /I "%_DeploySetParametersFile%" == "" (
set _DeploySetParametersFile=%RootPath%MYSITE.SetParameters.xml
)

@rem ------------------------------------------

@rem ------------------------------------------

                      
set _ArgTestDeploy=
set _ArgDestinationType=auto
set _ArgComputerNameWithQuote=""
set _ArgUserNameWithQuote=""
set _ArgPasswordWithQuote=""
set _ArgEncryptPasswordWithQuote=""
set _ArgIncludeAclsWithQuote="False"
set _ArgAuthTypeWithQuote=""
set _ArgtempAgentWithQuote=""
set _ArgLocalIIS=
set _ArgLocalIISVersion=
set _HaveArgMSDeployAdditonalFlags=
                      
                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Simple Parse the arguments
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:NextArgument
set _ArgCurrent=%~1
set _ArgFlagFirst=%_ArgCurrent:~0,1%
set _ArgFlag=%_ArgCurrent:~0,3%
set _ArgValue=%_ArgCurrent:~3%

if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "" goto :GetStarted
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "~0,3" goto :GetStarted
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/T" set _ArgTestDeploy=true&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/Y" set _ArgTestDeploy=false&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/L" set _ArgLocalIIS=true&goto :ArgumentOK

if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/M:" set _ArgComputerNameWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/U:" set _ArgUserNameWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/P:" set _ArgPasswordWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/E:" set _ArgEncryptPasswordWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/I:" set _ArgIncludeAclsWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/A:" set _ArgAuthTypeWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/G:" set _ArgtempAgentWithQuote="%_ArgValue%"&goto :ArgumentOK

@rem Any addition flags, pass through to the msdeploy
if "%_HaveArgMSDeployAdditonalFlags%" == "" (
goto :Assign_ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags
)
set _ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags:&=^&% %_ArgCurrent:&=^&%
set _HaveArgMSDeployAdditonalFlags=1
goto :ArgumentOK


:Assign_ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags
set _ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_ArgCurrent:&=^&%
set _HaveArgMSDeployAdditonalFlags=1
goto :ArgumentOK

:ArgumentOK
shift
goto :NextArgument

:GetStarted
@rem ------------------------------------------

@rem ------------------------------------------
if /I "%_ArgTestDeploy%" == "" goto :usage
if /I "%_ArgDestinationType%" == ""  goto :usage

set _Destination=%_ArgDestinationType%
if not %_ArgComputerNameWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,computerName=%_ArgComputerNameWithQuote%
if not %_ArgUserNameWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,userName=%_ArgUserNameWithQuote%
if not %_ArgPasswordWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,password=%_ArgPasswordWithQuote%
if not %_ArgAuthTypeWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,authtype=%_ArgAuthTypeWithQuote%
if not %_ArgEncryptPasswordWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,encryptPassword=%_ArgEncryptPasswordWithQuote%
if not %_ArgIncludeAclsWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,includeAcls=%_ArgIncludeAclsWithQuote%
if not %_ArgtempAgentWithQuote% == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,tempAgent=%_ArgtempAgentWithQuote%

@rem ------------------------------------------

@rem ------------------------------------------

                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem add -whatif when -T is specified                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if /I "%_ArgTestDeploy%" NEQ "false" (
set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=-whatif %_MsDeployAdditionalFlags%
)

@rem ------------------------------------------

@rem ------------------------------------------

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem add flags for IISExpress when -L is specified                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if /I "%_ArgLocalIIS%" == "true" (
call :SetIISExpressArguments
)
if /I "%_ArgLocalIIS%" == "true" (
if not exist "%IISExpressPath%%IISExpressManifest%" (
echo. IISExpress is not found on this machine. Please install through Web Platform Installer before execute the script. 
echo. or remove /L flag
echo. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
goto :usage
)
if not exist "%IISExpressUserProfileDirectory%" (
echo. %IISExpressUserProfileDirectory% is not exists
echo. IISExpress is found on the machine. But the user have run IISExpress at least once.
echo. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654 for detail
goto :usage
)
                      
set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_MsDeployAdditionalFlags% -appHostConfigDir:%IISExpressUserProfileDirectory% -WebServerDir:"%IISExpressPath%" -webServerManifest:"%IISExpressManifest%"
)

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem check the existence of the package file
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if not exist "%RootPath%MYSITE.zip" (
echo "%RootPath%MYSITE.zip" does not exist. 
echo This batch file relies on this deploy source file^(s^) in the same folder.
goto :usage
)

@rem ---------------------------------------------

@rem ---------------------------------------------

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Execute msdeploy.exe command line
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
call :CheckParameterFile
echo. Start executing msdeploy.exe
echo -------------------------------------------------------
if  not exist "%_DeploySetParametersFile%" (
set _MSDeployCommandline="%MSDeployPath%msdeploy.exe" -source:package='%RootPath%MYSITE.zip' -dest:%_Destination% -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension
) else (
set _MSDeployCommandline="%MSDeployPath%msdeploy.exe" -source:package='%RootPath%MYSITE.zip' -dest:%_Destination% -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"%_DeploySetParametersFile%"
)

if "%_HaveArgMSDeployAdditonalFlags%" == "" (
goto :MSDeployWithOutArgMsDeployAdditionalFlag
) 
goto :MSDeployWithArgMsDeployAdditionalFlag
goto :eof
```

But the task fails every time with this output (UPDATED with debug info):

```
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6148827Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'PowerShell Script MSDeploy'
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6150730Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6151232Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6152462Z ##[debug]=> True
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6152995Z ##[debug]Result: True
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6153704Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script MSDeploy
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6272897Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6273258Z Task         : PowerShell
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6273535Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6273811Z Version      : 2.180.1
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6274061Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6274475Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2021-04-20T19:07:28.6274845Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-20T19:07:31.1490744Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.11.0 commit 7ff27a3e0bdd6f7b06690ae5f5b63cb84d0f23f4
2021-04-20T19:07:31.2797508Z ##[debug]Entering D:\a\_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.180.1\powershell.ps1.
2021-04-20T19:07:31.2897797Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.180.1\task.json
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3295159Z ##[debug]Loaded 11 strings.
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3297151Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3302500Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.180.1\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3558737Z ##[debug]Loaded 11 strings.
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3818248Z ##[debug]INPUT_ERRORACTIONPREFERENCE: 'continue'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3892919Z ##[debug]INPUT_SHOWWARNINGS: 'false'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3894971Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3920563Z ##[debug]INPUT_FAILONSTDERR: 'false'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3938665Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3964198Z ##[debug]INPUT_IGNORELASTEXITCODE: 'false'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.3981567Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4006233Z ##[debug]INPUT_PWSH: 'false'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4023771Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4047897Z ##[debug]INPUT_WORKINGDIRECTORY: 'D:\a\r1\a'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4197124Z ##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\a\r1\a'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4223108Z ##[debug]INPUT_TARGETTYPE: 'inline'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4258556Z ##[debug]INPUT_SCRIPT: '_MYSITE-ASP.NET-CI-Try2\drop\MYSITE.deploy.cmd /Y /M:hardcoded /U:MYUSERNAME-001 /P:*** /G:False /A:Basic -allowUntrusted -enableRule:AppOffline'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4326516Z Generating script.
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4532300Z ##[debug]AGENT_VERSION: '2.185.1'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4621404Z ##[debug]AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY: 'D:\a\_temp'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.4643517Z ##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\a\_temp'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5057854Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5069825Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5289411Z ##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5414063Z ##[debug] Arguments: '-NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\b215ff73-d7c3-450f-8d2e-ba084962fdad.ps1'"'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5432905Z ##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5451721Z ##[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'D:\a\r1\a'
2021-04-20T19:07:31.5519638Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\b215ff73-d7c3-450f-8d2e-ba084962fdad.ps1'"
2021-04-20T19:07:32.8288668Z '@rem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2021-04-20T19:07:32.8289010Z 
2021-04-20T19:07:32.8303028Z operable program or batch file.
2021-04-20T19:07:32.8304928Z D:\a\r1\a>@rem --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9412552Z SetParameters from:
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9413166Z "D:\a\r1\a\_MYSITE-ASP.NET-CI-Try2\drop\MYSITE.SetParameters.xml"
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9414351Z You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9414841Z or other deploy parameters in the above file.
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9415646Z -------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9416057Z  Start executing msdeploy.exe
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9416816Z -------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-20T19:07:32.9418653Z  "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\_MYSITE-ASP.NET-CI-Try2\drop\MYSITE.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="https://dev.MYSITE.com:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=MYUSERNAME-001-subsite4",userName="MYUSERNAME-001",password="$(smarteraspnetPassword)",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False",tempAgent="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"D:\a\r1\a\_MYSITE-ASP.NET-CI-Try2\drop\MYSITE.SetParameters.xml"  -allowUntrusted -enableRule:AppOffline
2021-04-20T19:07:34.8012263Z Info: Using ID 'AGUIDWASHERE' for connections to the remote server.
2021-04-20T19:07:35.5683414Z Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED
2021-04-20T19:07:35.5685211Z More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("dev.MYSITE.com") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.
2021-04-20T19:07:35.5686550Z Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
2021-04-20T19:07:35.5687340Z Error count: 1.
2021-04-20T19:07:36.4391584Z ##[debug]$LASTEXITCODE: 1
2021-04-20T19:07:36.5105601Z ##[debug]Exit code: 1
2021-04-20T19:07:36.5166560Z ##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
2021-04-20T19:07:36.5599203Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2021-04-20T19:07:36.5609057Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2021-04-20T19:07:36.5636517Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected
2021-04-20T19:07:36.5695707Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.180.1\powershell.ps1.
2021-04-20T19:07:36.6389680Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script MSDeploy
```

UPDATE: I now think this has to do with the password somehow. I have verified that the correct password is in the smarteraspPassword variable (for every single scope, just in case). I have tried hardcoding it directly into the powershell task and I have also tried creating a Find/Replace task like the first two in the article to replace it directly into the deploy.cmd file itself. No matter what I do, when I try to echo that variable I always see three asterisks. When I try this locally I see the actual password that was passed in. Am I on to something or is this a wild goose chase due to DevOps knowing to mask it or something?

Comment: I am afraid this issue is not come from Azure devops, how about the result if you execute the same powershell scripts in you local machine? If it works fine in your local, please share the debug log of the pipeline, and more scripts for MYSITE.deploy.cmd, it seems the error log comes from the other scripts.

Comment: Thank you, I am able to run it fine locally and have replaced the log above with the detailed, debug log. Any ideas?

Comment: Agree with you. Based on you description and the log info `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`, this issue should be related to the `smarteraspnetPassword`, how about use the powershell inline instead of invoke .ps1, we copy the powershell scripts in the powershell inline with hardcodingsmarteraspPassword variable  it directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what you mean. The first code block above is what I'm using for my powershell inline. I have tried including the password directly in the inline and also doing a find/replace to put it directly into the deploy.cmd file as well.